# rpi4 add_event_detect event trigger

Tags: events, interrupt, gpio, raspberry-pi4

I have tried to implement interrupt on RPi4 with `add_event_detect()` function. My structure as following

input: gpio20, source signal
output: gpio21, light trigger signal

```python
entertime_stamp = time.time() 

''' config '''
INPUT_PIN = 20
OUTPUT_PIN = 21

''' gpio '''
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM) 
GPIO.setup(INPUT_PIN, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN) # pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN
GPIO.setup(OUTPUT_PIN, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.LOW) 
        
''' function for event trigger '''
def Interrupt(channel):
    global OUTPUT_PIN
    global GPIO
    global time_stamp       # put in to debounce  
    
    time_now = time.time()  
    if ((time_now - time_stamp) >= 0.3 and GPIO.input(INPUT_PIN)==1):  
    
        GPIO.output(OUTPUT_PIN, True)    
        
        time.sleep(0.2)
        GPIO.output(OUTPUT_PIN, False)
        
        print('Action trigger');
    
    time_stamp = time_now  

''' interrupt '''
GPIO.add_event_detect(INPUT_PIN, GPIO.RISING, callback = Interrupt, bouncetime = 200)


''' main '''
try:
    
    while True:
        print("input: {0}".format(GPIO.input(INPUT_PIN)))
            
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

My rule is to trigger gpio21 (0 to 1) when receive gpio20 signal rising, so I set `add_event_detect()` rule to "GPIO.RISING".

```python
GPIO.add_event_detect(INPUT_PIN, GPIO.RISING, callback = Interrupt, bouncetime = 200)
```

but it triggers gpio21(0 to 1) when receive gpio20 signal falling too. How to solve it?

Comment: Somewhere it thinks that you want to have signal on both edges. I would rather recommend to forger custom RPi GPIO library and switch to `libgpiod`. (It has Python bindings)

Comment: ok, i will try it